# Prototype-ui Carousel how to remember scroll position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, carousel

I am using http://www.prototype-ui.com/ Carousel and  i dont now how to remember scroll position after refresh page or after click on some item in div container! Every idea is wellcome thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cookie to remember the Carousel position: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: i try that but i am biginner and i dont now where to put a cookie in php script :( but thank you anywhere.